# Writing test cases for Http service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

Hi I have been trying to write test cases for my registration service. It has a url which it sends 4 values. the service is as follows:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'



interface registerResponse {
  success: boolean,
  message: string
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

private _regurl ="http://localhost:3000/api/register"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  registerUser(username,email,date,  password) {
   
    return this.http.post<registerResponse>(this._regurl, {
      username,
      email,
      date,
      password
      
     
    })
  }

}
```

I am still learning how to write test cases, i m trying to get the registerResponse to work.

here is what i have written till now

```js
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  HttpModule,
  Http,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions,
  XHRBackend
} from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'


describe('RegisterService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: HttpClient, useValue: 'http://localhost:3000/api/register' },
        AuthService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
      ]
    });
  });
```

I know its not much I hv only defined mockbackend but any help would be appriciated

Thank You

Comment: How can i check if the values of username email password etc are being submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin testing calls to `HttpClient`, import the `HttpClientTestingModule` and the mocking controller,`HttpTestingController`, along with the other symbols your tests require.

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
```

Then add the `HttpClientTestingModule` to the `TestBed` and continue with the setup of the service-under-test.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('RegisterService', () => {

  let service: AuthService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthService]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('#registerUser tests', () => {
    it('Should return registerResponse by making a POST request to the given url', () => {

      const username = 'username';
      const email = 'email';
      const date = 'date';
      const password = 'password';

      const mockResponse: RegisterResponse = {
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfull'
      };
      service.registerUser(username, email, date, password).subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toBe(mockResponse);
      });

      const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/api/register');
      expect(req.request.method).toBe('POST');
      req.flush(mockResponse);
    });
  });
});
```

Now requests made in your tests will hit the **testing backend** instead of the **normal backend**.

This setup also calls `TestBed.get()` to inject the mocking controller so it can be referenced during the tests.

The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.If no requests or multiple requests matched that URL `expectOne()` would throw.

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/api/register');
```

Read more about testing angular services that uses `HttpClient` and testing Http requests in [official angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).

In your service. Export the innterface.

```
export interface RegisterResponse {
  success: boolean,
  message: string
}
```

But I recommend you to move data models to a different directory or a file.

Then import the interface to the tes file like this.

```
import { RegisterResponse } from 'path-to-interface';
```

Comment: hi, It is not able to find registerResponse in:const mockResponse: registerResponse = {
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfull'
      };

Comment: In your service you have created an `interface` called **registerResponse**. Export the interface by adding `export` keyword infornt of the interface. Then import it to the test file. I'll update the answer

Comment: hi sorry for that silly question i figured it out. Thank you so much